# Angular reactive form or conditional validator

Tags: angular, forms, validation

Is it possible to declare validators for form group with or conditional logic so that at least one validator is true? 
like:

```js
this.fb.group({
            inboundAdapter: ['', [Validators.required]],
            inboundPort: ['993', [Validators.required]],
            // here i want at least 1 rexexp is true
            inboundHost: ['', Validators.pattern(this.domain_rexexp) || Validators.pattern(this.ip_rexexp)],
});
```

Comment: Make a custom validator that takes two validators and returns || results from each.

Comment: ok, so there is no way to specific or validator in fb.group params (without custom validator)?

Comment: I don't think so, no.

Comment: You could, of course, just make a regex that takes two regex expressions and OR them.